# Atualizar página apos download

Tags: java, jsf, download

Estou trabalhando em um pagina JSF e preciso realizar o download de um .pdf. Ao realizar o download o objeto é alterado e eu precisaria atualizá-lo pois não posso permitir o mesmo download mais do que uma vez.
Porem se eu usar `<f:ajax>` o download não funciona.

```
   <h:commandLink actionListener="#{repositorioCobrancaAddMB.clear}" 
                  title="${messages['label.print']}" 
                  rendered="#{repositorioCobrancaAddMB.podeGeraBoleto(bean)}"
                  class="btn btn-white">
             <span class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"/>
             <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="@all" listener="#{repositorioCobrancaAddMB.geraBoleto(bean)}"/>
     </h:commandLink>
```

Sem utilizar o ajax o download acontece, porem não atualiza a minha página!

```
     <h:commandLink action="#{repositorioCobrancaAddMB.geraBoleto(bean)}" 
                    actionListener="#{repositorioCobrancaAddMB.clear}" 
                    title="${messages['label.print']}" 
                    rendered="#{repositorioCobrancaAddMB.podeGeraBoleto(bean)}"
                    class="btn btn-white">
           <span class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"/>
      </h:commandLink>
```

Metodo que define se o usuário pode ou não gerar o boleto e os metodos de geração do boleto.

```
   public boolean podeGeraBoleto(Titulo bean) {
        return tituloBC.podeGeraBoleto(bean);
    }

    public String geraBoleto(Titulo bean) {
//        return "titulo_list.jsf";
        TituloTO tituloTO = tituloBC.geraTituloTO(bean);
        if (bean.getNossoNumero() == null || bean.getNossoNumero().isEmpty()) {
            tituloBC.geraNossoNumero(bean, tituloTO);
        } else {
            tituloTO.buildNossoNumeroTO();
        }
        if (tituloTO.getNossoNumeroTO() == null) {
            getMessageContext().add(getResourceBundle().getString("banco.msg.null"), SeverityType.WARN);
            return null;
        }

        byte[] pdf = GeraBoleto.gera(tituloTO);

        this.geraPDF(pdf, bean);

        return null;
    }

    public void geraPDF(byte[] pdf, Titulo bean) {
        if (pdf == null) {
            return;
        }

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();

        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + bean.getNumero() + " - " + bean.getParcela() + ".pdf");

        try {
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(pdf);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            CriareLog.log(ex);
        }
    }
```

TituloBC

```
public boolean podeGeraBoleto(Titulo bean) {
        if (bean.getSituacao().isLiquidado()) {
            return false;
        }
        return bean.getPortador().getBanco().isCobranca() && bean.getPortador().getBloquetoEmissao().isCliente();
    }
```

Alguém saberia como fazer para realizar o download e, ao termino dele, atualizar a página?

Comment: Mas precisa ser no termino do download? Não pode ser antes?

Comment: É que durante o processo de download eu mudo algumas informações do boleto, no caso, informo que ele já teve o boleto gerado e já possui informação bancária. Contanto que esta alteração aconteça, pode ser tando antes quanto depois.

Comment: Está usando Jsf 2.0?

Comment: Estou usando a versão 2.2.11 do JSF

Comment: @GilvanAndré Continua com o problema?

Comment: Bom dia... Desculpa a demora para responder. Este problema está ocorrendo em meu trabalho, e aonde eu moro é feriado na segunda, então passei 3 dias sem ter o que fazer! Estou retomando as atividades hoje. Mesmo assim obrigado pelas respostas e mais uma vez peço desculpas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível dar 2 respostas, sendo uma o download do arquivo e outro o redirect. Outra coisa, com o ajax não vai funcionar porque ele não responde com o download do arquivo.

Uma *gambirra* é criar uma condição no seu `.jsf` pra executar o download após atualizado.

No seu **managedBean** crie uma nova variável

```
private boolean downloadPronto = false;
```

No seu método `geraBoleto(Titulo bean)`

```
public String geraBoleto(Titulo bean)
{
    TituloTO tituloTO = tituloBC.geraTituloTO(bean);
    if (bean.getNossoNumero() == null || bean.getNossoNumero().isEmpty()) {
        tituloBC.geraNossoNumero(bean, tituloTO);
    } else {
        tituloTO.buildNossoNumeroTO();
    }
    if (tituloTO.getNossoNumeroTO() == null) {
        getMessageContext().add(getResourceBundle().getString("banco.msg.null"), SeverityType.WARN);
        return null;
    }

    // IMPORTATE NÃO GERAR O DOWNLOAD AINDA, SE NÃO SEU ATUALIZAR QUEBRA
    //byte[] pdf = GeraBoleto.gera(tituloTO);

    //this.geraPDF(pdf, bean);

    // CRIE ESSE ATRIBUTO INICILIZANDO COM `false` 
    // E ATUALIZE PRA SABER QUANDO ESTÁ PRONTO
    this.downloadPronto = true;

    return null;
}
```

Feito isso, no seu `.jsf` crie uma condição:

```
<c:if test="#{seuManagedBean.downloadPronto}">
     <script>
          window.onload = function() {
               document.getElementById('formDownload:link').onclick();
          }
     </script>

     /* pode deixar escondido visualmente, serve apenas pra disparar o download */
     <h:form id="formDownload">
          <h:commandLink id="link" action="#{seuManagedBean.downloadDireto()}"/>
     </h:form>
</c:if>
```

E no seu código crie o método `downloadDireto`

```
public String downloadDireto() {
    TituloTO tituloTO = tituloBC.geraTituloTO(bean);

    byte[] pdf = GeraBoleto.gera(tituloTO);
    this.geraPDF(pdf, bean);

    this.downloadPronto = false; // reseta variavel

    return null;
}
```

Basicamente como funciona, quando você clica no botão que você já tem ele vai atualizar os valores e atualizar a variável nova `downloadPronto` pra verdadeiro, quando voltar pra página ele vai entrar na condição do `c:if` e vai chamar o `click` do botão pra ai sim fazer download sem precisar atualizar os valores.

Comment: por exemplo "repositorio_edit.jsf?faces-redirect=true"?

Comment: Ainda não testei, vou testar agora. Um minuto

Comment: Testei e infelizmente não funcionou!

Comment: Dessa forma executa o método, só não faz o download do arquivo

Comment: mantive ele no commandlik

Comment: Usar ele com o ajax? sem o ajax não funcionou

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25249/discussion-between-maicon-carraro-and-gilvan-andre).

Comment: Reformulei toda minha resposta, da uma olhada :)

Comment: A partir disso fiz umas adaptações e funcionou! Não é exatamente como eu gostaria, mas o que mais me interessa é o funcionamento!

Comment: Por hora agradeço!

Answer (score 0):

Substitua por isso :

```
public void geraBoleto(Titulo bean) {

    TituloTO tituloTO = tituloBC.geraTituloTO(bean);
    if (bean.getNossoNumero() == null || bean.getNossoNumero().isEmpty()) {
        tituloBC.geraNossoNumero(bean, tituloTO);
    } else {
        tituloTO.buildNossoNumeroTO();
    }
    if (tituloTO.getNossoNumeroTO() == null) {
        getMessageContext().add(getResourceBundle().getString("banco.msg.null"), SeverityType.WARN);
        return null;
    }

    byte[] pdf = GeraBoleto.gera(tituloTO);

    this.geraPDF(pdf, bean);

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().
    redirect("nomeDaSuaPagina.jsf");


}
```

Comment: apaguei a outra

Comment: Ola. Eu fiz as alterações que você sugeriu, mas continuo com o mesmo problema! Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Tente utilizar o `update`:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{repositorioCobrancaAddMB.geraBoleto(bean)}" 
                    actionListener="#{repositorioCobrancaAddMB.clear}" 
                    title="${messages['label.print']}" 
                    rendered="#{repositorioCobrancaAddMB.podeGeraBoleto(bean)}"
                    class="btn btn-white"
                    update=":SEU_FORM">
           <span class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"/>
      </h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Eu não estou utilizando o componente do PrimeFaces. O componente do JSF não tem esta opção.